# Error, while creating telegram bot

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, telegram-bot

I'm creating Telegram Bot using asp .net Core Web API. I have strange exception

> HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found)."

in Configure method in Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseMvc();

            Bot.GetBotClientAsync().Wait(); // exception here
// AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).)
        }
```

Here is my GetBotClientAsync() method in Bot.cs

```
public static async Task<TelegramBotClient> GetBotClientAsync()
        {
            if (botClient != null)
            {
                return botClient;
            }

            commandsList = new List<Command>();
            commandsList.Add(new StartCommand());

            botClient = new TelegramBotClient(AppSettings.Key);
            string hook = string.Format(AppSettings.Url, "api/message/update");
            await botClient.SetWebhookAsync(hook); // also exception here
//HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
            return botClient;
        }
```

How I've done wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: A 404 (Not Found) usually means you got the URL wrong. Verify that `hook` has the correct URL

Comment: What value does `AppSettings.Url` have?

Comment: @phuzi  `"https://URL:443/{0}"`

Comment: Is the hostname actually `URL`?

Comment: @phuzi how can i check, is the hostname actually url?

Comment: in `"https://URL:443/{0}"` "URL" is the hostname that your service/app is available on. It's likely that this endpoint will need to be valid.

Comment: Could also be possible that you're unable to connect to the API at `"https://api.telegram.org/bot/"` Are you behind a firewall/proxy

Comment: @phuzi it was an error with telegram token, btw thank u for help